# Unable to install createrepo.noarch

Tags: linux, unix, rpm, yum, rhel

I created a new EC2 on AWS, using RHEL 8. I try to do `sudo yum install createrepo.noarch`

But I get back this error:

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Last metadata expiration check: 2:00:24 ago on Sat 29 May 2021 05:02:03 PM UTC.
No match for argument: createrepo.noarch
Error: Unable to find a match: createrepo.noarch
```

Anyone know how I can get around this error?

I thought about downloading one of them from https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=createrepo, but no idea which one I'm supposed to download.

Comment: you need to pay for a  redhat subscription...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register your system first:

```
# subscription-manager register
```

And use your username and password which you used when you bought Red Hat subscription.

If you do not want to pay, you can use CentOS Stream 8, which is free.